# How to make a SQL query to select rows with dynamic interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table currency history with the following structure:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+---------------------+
| id | currency_id | price_usd     | created_at          |
+----+-------------+---------------+---------------------+
|  1 |           1 | 8719.79000000 | 2019-11-12 15:52:06 |
|  2 |           2 |  185.36000000 | 2019-11-12 15:52:06 |
|  3 |           3 |    0.27157609 | 2019-11-12 15:52:06 |
|  4 |           4 |  287.40000000 | 2019-11-12 15:52:06 |
|  5 |           5 |    1.00000000 | 2019-11-12 15:52:06 |
|  1 |           1 | 8719.79000000 | 2019-11-12 15:58:06 |
|  2 |           2 |  185.36000000 | 2019-11-12 15:58:06 |
|  3 |           3 |    0.27157609 | 2019-11-12 15:58:06 |
|  4 |           4 |  287.40000000 | 2019-11-12 15:58:06 |
|  5 |           5 |    1.00000000 | 2019-11-12 15:58:06 |
+----+-------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

And now I need to do some date filters to this table, for example, I need to select 1 row per hour for last 7 days. Column `created_at` is dynamic. How can I do that in properly way?

**UPD**: mysql database, InnoDB.

**UPD2**: expected result is:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+---------------------+
| id | currency_id | price_usd     | created_at          |
+----+-------------+---------------+---------------------+
|  1 |           1 | 8719.79000000 | 2019-11-12 15:52:06 |
|  2 |           1 | 8719.79000000 | 2019-11-12 16:52:06 |
|  3 |           1 | 8719.79000000 | 2019-11-12 17:52:06 |
|  4 |           1 | 8719.79000000 | 2019-11-12 18:52:06 |
|  5 |           1 | 8719.79000000 | 2019-11-12 19:52:06 |
|  6 |           1 | 8719.79000000 | 2019-11-12 20:58:06 |
|  7 |           1 | 8719.79000000 | 2019-11-12 21:58:06 |
|  8 |           1 | 8719.79000000 | 2019-11-12 22:58:06 |
|  9 |           1 | 8719.79000000 | 2019-11-12 23:58:06 |
| 10 |           1 | 8719.79000000 | 2019-11-13 00:58:06 |
+----+-------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

Interval between rows should be not less than 1 hour

Comment: @GordonLinoff my bad, changed the question

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: @jarlh done *symbols to send this comment*

Comment: What is `id` in this context? See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` with date functions.

```
select ch.*
from (select ch.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date(created_at), hour(created_at) order by created_at) as seqnum
      from currency_history ch
      where created_at >= curdate() - interval 6 day
     ) ch
where seqnum = 1;
```